# Is there a Console or Log view in SQL Server Enterprise Manager

Tags: sql-server, logging

Is there a console or log view which can be accessed within SQL Server Enterprise Manager that would show me the SQL statement which was ran as a result of changing something using the GUI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to see how SSMS is doing something you can use SQL Profiler and monitor the commands from sent to the database.

Comment: You can also filter the Profiler data by Host, so only interactions from your machine appear. This helps when sharing a dev server with a team.

Answer (score 0):

Many of the dialogues have a Script button (often top left of the dialog) which gives options to generate a script equivalent of pressing OK. Ie. select the script after choosing the options you want and before pressing OK (and often you'll want to press Cancel instead).

This doesn't provide for determining the SQL retrospectively.